# Time tracking in Java: using currentTimeMills()

Tags: java, time

I got an interesting "time-travel" problem today, using the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Some code here
    System.out.print(i + "\t" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Some code here
    System.out.println("\t" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
}
```

And I got the result

```
0   15  -606
```

And it seems that it is not repeatable. Anyone has any clues on what happened inside during the running time? Just curious...

New edit: I used a small test to confirmed the answers below. I run the program and change the system time during the run, and finally repeat the "time-travel":

```
0   -3563323    163
```

Case closed. Thanks guys!

More words: both currentTimeMillis() and nanoTime() are system-timer based, so they will be not monotonic if the system timer is updated (turned back, specifically). It is better to use some internet-based timer for such cases.

Comment: Not sure `currentTimeMillis` is monotonic. You may have better results wit `System.nanoTime()` which is designed especially to measure intervals.

Comment: @asksw0rder : can you run same program again and update what second output is?

Comment: @asksw0rder What is the variable i? what is it value? Makes no sense to get 0 in the first output.

Comment: Possible Duplicates: [How do I measure elapsed time in Java?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770010/how-do-i-measure-time-elapsed-in-java

Comment: @bchetty : not duplicate... plsss....

Comment: Are you using some sort of network time synchronization to keep your computer time up-to-date? I guess it could have been caused by the synchronization correcting "drift" in the system clock.

Comment: @FahimParkar Cannot repeat it any more... So I think it is just because that the system time is changed.

Comment: @sfrj i is actually for a loop starting from 0... I missed the code for the loop...

Comment: hmmm... Cool that problem is solved...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` depends on the system time. So it could be modified by third party systems.

For measuring time is `System.nanoTime()` the better option.

Comment: nanoTime() is not ok for such case either. It is better to use internet-based time.

Comment: I didn't say that it's the best option, just a better than `System.currentTimeMillis()`! .. it's tricky to measure nano seconds over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I recall something like time adjustments made to the systems time once in a while too match actual time. And since currentTimeMillis relies on the system clock that might have happened. Also are you synchronizing with a time server, that could also be.