# Logging Session Scoped Bean Initialization Time

Tags: java, spring, session

I have an issue with my web application and I suspect that the session scoped beans are taking a long time to load.

Is there a way I can log how long the beans are taking to initialize?

Comment: *Is there a way I can log how long the beans are taking to initialize?* yes, in a `@PostConstruct` method. But since we don't have any code to inspect, we cannot say if the issue is there or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple time logging mechanism along [these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770010/how-do-i-measure-time-elapsed-in-java) setting the start time at the beginning of your constructor and the end time in a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`. This should give you a good idea how much time Spring takes to initialize your bean and wire up its dependencies.

Comment: Does the constructor get called before or after the dependencies are injected? I need to include the dependency injection time as well in the initialized time that I am measuring.

Comment: Default constructor gets called before dependency injection

Answer (score 0):

A simple log4j configuration should enable you to understand how long which bean(s) are taking. Set the logging level to DEBUG and use the date/time format in the log4j appender to print out the times.

Answer (score 0):

SLF4j (that can easily be used with Spring: the reason why I found that) has a special TimeInstrument implementation for such purposes: [[StopWatch]](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/profiler/StopWatch.html)

Maybe this helps somebody, even though this question is a little old.

**EDIT:** The nice thing about it: it actually uses nanoTime() which is - according to these posts[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/180191/4958869), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1776053/4958869)] - the most precise solution.

(Code snippet from org.slf4j.profiler.StopWatch.start(String) )

```
public void start(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    status = TimeInstrumentStatus.STARTED;
}
```