# Time difference between clock() time in c++ and System.CurrentTimeMillis() in java

Tags: java, c++

**What i do:**

1.I called a c++ method from java by generating wrapper using the swig intermediate file.

2.I used clock() time inside c++ code, to calculate the total time taken in the method writtern in c++(Differnce from start to end) .

```
       clock_t start=clock();
       clock_t end=clock();
       double elapsed_secs = double(end - start) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000;
```

3.In the java, i used ***System.CurrentTimeMillis()*** to calculate the time taken to call the method.

**What i have to know:**

When calculating the both difference in milliseconds,it was found that the time difference taken inside the c++ is more than the time difference while calling the method in java.

1.How the time taken while calling the method from java is less than the toatal time taken inside the method?

2.Is there any difference between the clock() time and the System.CurrentTimeMillis()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note I'm not a Java programmer.

1) `System.currentTimeMillis` isn't comparable to `clock`

Depending on implementation (see 2), `clock` will return (roughly) how long your program has been executing. `System.currentTimeMillis` returns UNIX time in milliseconds, which isn't quite correct compared to `clock`. It's also worth mentioning `currentTimeMillis` is also platform dependant.

On the Java side, you should be using `System.nanoTime()`, see [How do I measure time elapsed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770010/how-do-i-measure-time-elapsed-in-java)

2) `clock` is defined differently on different platforms.

Put simply, whether `clock` returns Wall Time or CPU Time is dependant on the platform you're  on.

To match `System.nanoTime()` to measure CPU time, use `std::clock` with `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`. You can see a working example here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock

Comment: Yes, currentTimeMillis updates not as good as nanoTime (but is more efficient). clock is more compatible with nanoTime.

Comment: @JoopEggen but what `clock` actually measures differs between Windows and Linux, on Windows it measures clock time ("real time"), on Linux it measures CPU time. If any sleeping is done, measurement between platforms will differ wildly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply@ 058 094 041

Comment: @CibinWilliam and thank you for coming back to accept it :)