# Why am I getting 7 hours extra when I time something using this code?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have tried the following code and still get the same results:

Code1

```
    long start=System.currentTimeMillis();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    long finish=System.currentTimeMillis();

    Date date1 = new Date(finish- start);
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
    String dateFormatted = formatter.format(date1);
    System.out.println(dateFormatted);
```

Code2

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(appTerminateTime - appStartTime);
    return "session lasted for " + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you are using Java 8 then using `Instant` and `Duration` would avoid time zone issues.

Comment: Why are you setting date1 to a time instant not long after jan 1 1970?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the extra hours is because of the difference between your time zone and the default GMT of the JVM when creating the [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date(long)).

It's not clear what session length you're trying to measure, but you might consider `System.nanoTime()` for a more precise length of measurement since using `System.currentTimeMillis()` may introduce errors as it has corrections for *wall-clock* time as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770010/how-do-i-measure-time-elapsed-in-java) answer.