# Comparing the time difference of sorting using Monte Carlo simulation (Java)

Tags: java, montecarlo

I want to compare the time difference (Time required for..) Bubble Sort, Insertion Sort, and Selection Sort using Monte Carlo Simulation and output the time differences using Java.

I am still a beginner in java and don't understand completely how to use monte carlo simulation.

These are the sorting programs I want to use monte carlo to compare the time differential:

Bubble Sort:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class sort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Number of elements in array: ");

int n = in.nextInt();
int []a = new int[n];
System.out.println("Enter integer values: ");
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) 
{
    a[i]=in.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("UnSorted array: "+ Arrays.toString(a));         
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {

    for(int j=1; j<n; j++) {

        if(a[j-1]>a[j]) {

            int temp = a[j-1];
            a[j-1]=a[j];
            a[j]=temp;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Sorted array: "+ Arrays.toString(a));

//Time Complexity: O(n*n)
//Space Complexity: O(1)


}

}
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of elements of array
5
Enter the integer array
-2
4
22
45
-60
UnSorted array: [-2, 4, 22, 45, -60]
Sorted array: [-60, -2, 4, 22, 45]
```

Selection Sort:

```
class SelectionSort
{
void sort(int arr[])
{
int n = arr.length;

// One by one move boundary of unsorted subarray
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{
    // Find the minimum element in unsorted array
    int min_idx = i;
    for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        if (arr[j] < arr[min_idx])
            min_idx = j;

    // Swap the found minimum element with the first
    // element
    int temp = arr[min_idx];
    arr[min_idx] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = temp;
}
}

// Prints the array
void printArray(int arr[])
{
int n = arr.length;
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
System.out.println();
}

// Driver code to test above
public static void main(String args[])
{
SelectionSort ob = new SelectionSort();
int arr[] = {64,25,12,22,11};
ob.sort(arr);
System.out.println("Sorted array");
ob.printArray(arr);
}
}
```

Output:

```
Sorted array
11 12 22 25 64
```

Insertion Sort:

```
class InsertionSort
 {
 /*Function to sort array using insertion sort*/
void sort(int arr[])
{
int n = arr.length;
for (int i=1; i<n; ++i)
{
    int key = arr[i];
    int j = i-1;

    /* Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are
       greater than key, to one position ahead
       of their current position */
    while (j>=0 && arr[j] > key)
    {
        arr[j+1] = arr[j];
        j = j-1;
    }
    arr[j+1] = key;
}
}

/* A utility function to print array of size n*/
static void printArray(int arr[])
{
int n = arr.length;
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");

System.out.println();
}

// Driver method
public static void main(String args[])
{        
int arr[] = {12, 11, 13, 5, 6};

InsertionSort ob = new InsertionSort();        
ob.sort(arr);

printArray(arr);
}
}
```

Output:

```
5 6 11 12 13
```

Comment: Look at how you measure time elapsed - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770010/how-do-i-measure-time-elapsed-in-java