# Jav8: Computing Elapsed time for Timestamp

Tags: java, performance, optimization, timestamp

I have the below code to get Current Timestamp and compute the Last Timestamp's elapsed time in minutes, am wondering if this can be optimized further for production

```
public static Timestamp getTimestamp() {
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();       
    long time = date.getTime();          
    java.sql.Timestamp ts = new java.sql.Timestamp(time);
    return ts;
}

public static long getLastTimestampElapse(java.sql.Timestamp oldTime){
  long milliseconds1 = oldTime.getTime();
  long milliseconds2 = getTimestamp().getTime();
  long diff = milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;      
  long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);      
  return diffMinutes;
}
```

Comment: You do you need the `Timestamp`? You can just use `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: For true elapsed time, do not use the milliseconds or current time. You need to use nano time. There is a lot of discussion on SO, but see [the answer on measurement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770010/how-do-i-measure-time-elapsed-in-java).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I measure time elapsed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770010/how-do-i-measure-time-elapsed-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

From Java 8 upwards you can use the [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class:

```
Timestamp timestamp = ...;
Duration duration = Duration.between(timestamp.toInstant(), Instant.now());
long diffMinutes = duration.toMinutes();
System.out.println(diffMinutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use stopwatch, details here:
http://commons.apache.org/lang/

Package: 
org.apache.commons.lang.time.StopWatch