# Start and Stop time of a function keeps returning 0 or 1

Tags: java, recursion, runtime

I'm doing a homework assignment where we're testing the runtime of a couple algorithms (greatest common divisor, or GCD) using 10-digit prime numbers.

We are to capture the runtime as milliseconds, which I capture using `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

The way I do it is to have a start time variable and a stop time variable, then find the difference between those two in another variable.

So far, it works perfectly for one method, but returns 0 or 1 for the other method.

I went through the debugger, and it seemed to work correctly, but when I run it, it returns 0 or 1.

Here are the variables I'm using and the main method. The commented-out line works as intended, but the `fastgcd` method is the one that returns 0 or 1.

```
public class GCD {

    public static long startTime;
    public static long stopTime;
    public static long elapsedTime;

    public GCD(){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //System.out.println(gcd(3267000013L, 1500450271L));
        System.out.println(fastgcd(3267000013L, 1500450271L));

        stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(Long.toString(elapsedTime));
    }
```

Here's the method that works:

```
public static String gcd(long a, long b) {
        long n = Long.min(a, b);
        for (long i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
            if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0) {
                return "Done";
            }
        }
        // If error
        return null;
    }
```

And here's the method that doesn't work:

```
public static String fastgcd(long a, long b){
        if(b == 0){
            return "Done";
        }
        else{
            return fastgcd(b, a%b);
        }
    }
```

So for the method that works, I will get somewhere between 12000 - 12500 milliseconds for a 10-digit number.

The `fastgcd` method returns 0 or 1 milliseconds, which isn't right, especially a 10-digit prime number.

No idea where it's going wrong...

Comment: `which isn't right` are you sure?

Comment: Count the number if iterations for the first one vs the second.

Comment: How confident are you that 1ms must be wrong? The first formula is doing literally tens of millions of times more work.

Comment: And another hint: **never** include print statements within your measurement! Printing to the console can take significant amounts of time, and also vary greatly. So: exclude printing. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java ... you dont need to apply everything. But you should at least understand what problems you should consider when benchmarking code.

Comment: hmm... ran it through the debugger and even with a 10-digit number it didn't take long. Maybe 0 or 1 is in fact accurate ‍♂️

Comment: @GhostCat I know, but it's what the teacher wanted.

Comment: Then tell your teacher that GhostCat from the interwebs told you to ask your money back. That, or politely send him that link I gave youl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine (in terms of getting time), and the values that you're getting are "correct".  What you're measuring is wall-clock time (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770010/how-do-i-measure-time-elapsed-in-java)), which is inherently slightly inaccurate, and also not granular enough to measure code that is running as quickly as your `fastgcd` method.

For measuring elapsed time with a high degree of precision, use `System.nanoTime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: that makes sense, tried it and it works. Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 0):

If you run your method and check the recursion count, it will be called recursively **only 19 times**. And for these modern days compiler and machines, it is not huge operation. So completing it in 1 millisecond is totally justified. If you check it in nanoseconds using `System.nanoTime()`, `fastgcd` is taking around 280675 nanoseconds on my **Windows machine Java 8, 32 GB RAM and 8th Gen Core I7**. So nothing going wrong here.

Comment: To expand on what you said, 280675 is .28 milliseconds, which rounds down to 0 because it is returned as a `long` and does not hold decimals with `.currentTimeMillis()` and does not have the precision of `.nanoTime()`.