# Does JMH calculate operations per time unit based on CPU time or on wall-clock time?

Tags: java, benchmarking, jmh, cpu-time

Considering the default usage of the JMH, I would like to make sure which type of time JMH bases its measurements on: CPU time or Wall-clock.

I tried looking into the JMH official samples (https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), tutorials (at Jenkov, Baeldung, Mykong and others), and did not manage to find this information precisely (I acknowledge I might have missed some documentation or general information on benchmarks).

For instance, in Sample 35 (https://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/99d7b73cf1e3/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_35_Profilers.java), we have as an example of output:

```
        Benchmark                              (type)  Mode  Cnt     Score    Error   Units

          JMHSample_35_Profilers.Maps.test     hashmap  avgt    5  1553.201 Â±   6.199   ns/op

          JMHSample_35_Profilers.Maps.test     treemap  avgt    5  5177.065 Â± 361.278   ns/op
```

Hence, I would like to know if the Score column was calculated using Wall-clock time or CPU Time so that I can accurately interpret the benchmark results.

Comment: Maybe you can find you answer by checking the source code of jmh at https://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/99d7b73cf1e3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I feared, I had missed basic information and formulated my question badly since wall-clock and CPU times are not the only options. I followed Alexandre Cartapanis' suggestion and looked into JMH's source code. I found out that the class [BenchmarkGenerator](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/99d7b73cf1e3/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/generators/core/BenchmarkGenerator.java), which produces the benchmarks, relies on System.nanoTime().

Further, according to [System.nanoTime() documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--) and [Kevin Bourrillion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770010/how-do-i-measure-time-elapsed-in-java/1776053#1776053) to another question I concluded that JMH, by default, measures time according to some arbitrary, but fixed, source (just like System.nanoTime()).